# tpl how to use php in tpl file to display variable

Tags: php, smarty

In tpl file I have

```
<span>{$language->name|escape}</span>
```

it displays

```
pl_PL
```

How to display only ladt two signs? Using some filters or {php} {/php} ?

Comment: You want to display only `PL`? It would be best to assign a variable in the PHP code by extracting it from the `$language->name` with simple string methods, and then making that variable available to smarty.

Comment: If you can't do what @MichaelBerkowski says, then remember you can always use php function directly in smarty: `{$language->name|substring:-2|escape}`, although I strongly recommend modifying variables in php and assigning final values to smarty.

Comment: substring:-2 would be great resolving but I'm working on shoper not prestashop and id does not work

Comment: How to call `$language->name` in `{php} {/php}` ?

Comment: correct is: `<span>{$language->name|substr:-2|escape}</span>' not `substring` !